# How to turn a tornado HTTPRequest into a Django HttpRequest or WSGIRequest?

Tags: python, django, socket.io, tornado, django-wsgi

I'm writing a socket.io app using Django and TornadIO2/Tornado. In the TonradIO2 Session, I have access to Tornado's HTTPRequest objects. However, I have no access to a django request object in my event handlers in the SocketConnection class. Ideally, I'd like all the configured django middlewhere to execute on the request object before reaching my event handlers. I could call them the middlewhere explicitly, but I need to convert the HTTPRequest object to a Django HttpRequest or a Django WSGIRequest object first. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado has [WSGIContainer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/wsgi.html#wsgicontainer), which "makes a WSGI-compatible function runnable on Tornado’s HTTP server" and "-- intended to let other frameworks (Django, web.py, etc) run on the Tornado HTTP server and I/O loop."

Comment: Using a WSGIContainer would bypass TornadIO's socket.io protocol handling. What I'd like to do is use TornadIO as the socket.io communication protocol handler, but then invoke Django's magic before the events are passed to my event listeners.

Comment: I ended up using `WSGIContainer` and found a way to make it still use TornadIO2 for socket.io handling. See sample code at https://github.com/tgcondor/django-tornadio2/blob/master/django_tornadio2/management/commands/runserver_tornadio2.py. Thanks for the answer.